# Creating a struct with an array (Matrices)

Tags: arrays, rust

I'm currently working on a simple project to get myself familiar with Rust. I don't have much systems programming experience but I'm hoping to learn!

I'm trying to create a Matrix struct but I'm finding it hard to figure out how I should store the data. I feel like I should be able to use an array. The size of the matrix must be defined on construction and so I would hope I can store the array on the stack.

Right now my code looks like this:

```
use std::ops::Mul;
use std::ops::Add;
use std::ops::Div;

struct Matrix {
    cols: i32,
    rows: i32,
    // Of course this doesn't work!
    data: [f32; ..cols*rows]
}

// Below here are a bunch of stub methods.
impl Mul<f32> for Matrix {
    type Output = Matrix;

    fn mul(self, m: f32) -> Matrix {
        return self;
    }
}

impl Mul<Matrix> for Matrix {
    type Output = Matrix;

    fn mul(self, m: Matrix) -> Matrix {
        // Will use Strassen algorithm if large, traditional otherwise
        return self;
    }
}

impl Add<Matrix> for Matrix {
    type Output = Matrix;

    fn add(self, m: Matrix) -> Matrix {
        return self;
    }
}

impl Div<f32> for Matrix {
    type Output = Matrix;

    fn div(self, f: f32) -> Matrix {
        return self;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be with  a `Vec`.

```
struct Matrix {
    cols: i32,
    rows: i32,
    data: Vec<f32>
}

impl Matrix {
    fn new(cols: i32, rows: i32) -> Matrix {
        Matrix {
            cols: cols,
            rows: rows,
            data: vec![0.0; cols * rows]
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want to store the data on the heap, you could make `Matrix` into a dynamically sized type, but this is hard to do and isn't really supported. See [a Reddit thread on that topic](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/2nkdxn/structs_with_a_variable_size/).

If you don't want to use a `Vec` but are okay with storing the data on the heap, you could use a boxed slice instead (`Box<[f32]>`). See [`Vec::into_boxed_slice`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.into_boxed_slice) for one way to create one.

And of course, if you really don't want to use the heap, you could make different `Matrix` types for different sizes of matrices. This is what the crate [nalgebra](http://nalgebra.org/doc/nalgebra/struct.Mat2.html) does.

Comment: Thanks for the response - it's helped me understand what's going on a bit more.

Dynamic sizing looks plausible but I agree it's a hassle and I'm not sure it would let me do things like make the default matrix all zeros (without feeding in an array to the constructor).

I would like to have the data on the stack but for now I'll try an implementation using boxed slices. Thanks!

Comment: I checked out the code for nalgebra. The problem is I'm planning on using this in a machine learning setting - so matrices of huge sizes will be common D:

Comment: @user124784 Probably best to use the heap then, since storing huge things on the stack is generally a bad idea.

Comment: Small advice: If you want to do serious work with huge matrices, you should consider using a library. Making matrix operations (very) fast is difficult and popular libraries are usually at least ten times faster than something a normal intelligent programmer could write.

Comment: Lukas - I'm using this project as a way to get familiar with Rust (and systems programming). I'm not expecting to make anything that can be used for serious applications :). Thank you for taking the time to comment though.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use a vector of vector (`Vec<Vec<T>>`), without implementing your own `Matrix` or using a library. But this is slighly slower than Adrian's approach in terms of indexing. `nalgebra` is good at vectorized computation, but it performs worse than simple matrices made of `Vec<T>` or `Vec<Vec<T>>` when it comes to elementwise operation. Here are some benchmarks:

```
test bench_vec               ... bench:  84,694,933 ns/iter (+/- 7,412,836)
test bench_vec_of_vec        ... bench:  87,083,636 ns/iter (+/- 1,171,842)
test bench_vec_unsafe        ... bench:  41,440,947 ns/iter (+/- 752,463)
test bench_vec_of_vec_unsafe ... bench:  44,532,595 ns/iter (+/- 629,209)
test bench_nalgebra          ... bench: 452,872,630 ns/iter (+/- 40,284,295)
```

```rust
#![feature(test)]

extern crate test;
use na::Matrix;
use na::{Dynamic, VecStorage};
use nalgebra as na;

type DMatrixi32 = Matrix<u8, Dynamic, Dynamic, VecStorage<u8, Dynamic, Dynamic>>;

use test::Bencher;

#[bench]
fn bench_vec_of_vec(b: &mut Bencher) {
    let (m, n) = (10000, 10000);
    let mut matrix = vec![vec![0u8; n]; m];
    b.iter(|| {
        for i in 0..m {
            for j in 0..n {
                matrix[i][j] = 1u8;
            }
        }
    });
}

#[bench]
fn bench_vec(b: &mut Bencher) {
    let (m, n) = (10000, 10000);
    let mut matrix = vec![0u8; n * m];
    b.iter(|| {
        for i in 0..m {
            for j in 0..n {
                matrix[i * n + j] = 1u8;
            }
        }
    });
}

#[bench]
fn bench_vec_of_vec_unsafe(b: &mut Bencher) {
    let (m, n) = (10000, 10000);
    let mut matrix = vec![vec![0u8; n]; m];
    b.iter(|| {
        for i in 0..m {
            for j in 0..n {
                unsafe {
                    *matrix.get_unchecked_mut(i).get_unchecked_mut(j) = 1u8;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

#[bench]
fn bench_vec_unsafe(b: &mut Bencher) {
    let (m, n) = (10000, 10000);
    let mut matrix = vec![0u8; n * m];
    b.iter(|| {
        for i in 0..m {
            for j in 0..n {
                unsafe { *matrix.get_unchecked_mut(i * n + j) = 1u8 };
            }
        }
    });
}

#[bench]
fn bench_nalgebra(b: &mut Bencher) {
    let (m, n) = (10000, 10000);
    let mut matrix = DMatrixi32::from_vec(m, n, vec![0u8; n * m]);
    b.iter(|| {
        for i in 0..m {
            for j in 0..n {
                matrix[(i, j)] = 1u8;
            }
        }
    });
}
```